# How to run embedded function

Tags: function, powershell, nested, scoping

I am setting up a small script for a team of exchange admins at our MSP, the script consists of a 4 main functions and within these functions are more functions. I am having some trouble running the embedded functions. Below I have put an example of one of these functions "Manage-Teams"

I have added a Switch ($option) to see if this would resolve the issue, originally I had $option = Read-host -prompt "some text"

This did resolve the issue however I could not find it when tabbing through the functions

```
function Manage-Teams() {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "What would you like to do? <Enable-AddGuests/Home>"
    $option = Write-Host 'Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuest'
    function Enable-AddGuests () {

            #Set specific Group back to $True or $False
            # GroupID is <Name.ExcterDirectoryObjectId>
        $GroupID = get-unifiedgroup -Identity (Read-Host -prompt "object ID or SMTP") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExternalDirectoryObjectId
        $SettingID = Get-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID | select-object -expandproperty ID
        remove-azureadobjectsetting -id $settingid -targettype Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID
        $template = Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate | ? {$_.displayname -eq "group.unified.guest"}
        $settingsCopy = $template.CreateDirectorySetting()
        $settingsCopy["AllowToAddGuests"]= True
        New-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $groupID -DirectorySetting $settingsCopy
    }

    function Disable-AddGuests {

        #Set specific Group back to $True or $False
        # GroupID is <Name.ExcterDirectoryObjectId>
    $GroupID = get-unifiedgroup -Identity (Read-Host -prompt "object ID or SMTP") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExternalDirectoryObjectId
    $SettingID = Get-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID | select-object -expandproperty ID
    remove-azureadobjectsetting -id $settingid -targettype Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID
    $template = Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate | ? {$_.displayname -eq "group.unified.guest"}
    $settingsCopy = $template.CreateDirectorySetting()
    $settingsCopy["AllowToAddGuests"]= False
    New-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $groupID -DirectorySetting $settingsCopy
}
    Switch ($option) 
    {
        Enable-AddGuests {Enable-AddGuests}
        Disable-AddGuests {Disable-AddGuests}
        Home {Home}
    }
}
```

I am hoping for the following:

> Manage-teams
>    "what would you like to do"
>   Enable-AddGuests
>    Runs function to enable guest access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your script for demonstration purposes.

```
Function Manage-Teams {

    $option = Read-Host "Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuests"


    Function script:Enable-AddGuests {
        "Executing Enable-AddGuests"
    }
    Function script:Disable-AddGuests {
        "Executing Disable-AddGuests"
    }

    Switch ($option) {
        'Enable-AddGuests' {Enable-AddGuests}
        'Disable-AddGuests' {Disable-AddGuests}
        Default {"Entered an incorrect option"}
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Manage-Teams
Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuests: Enable-AddGuests
Executing Enable-AddGuests
Manage-Teams
Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuests: Disable-AddGuests
Executing Disable-AddGuests
Manage-Teams
Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuests: HelpMe
Entered an incorrect option

Get-Help Enable-AddGuests

NAME
    Enable-AddGuests

SYNTAX
    Enable-AddGuests


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None



Get-Help Disable-AddGuests

NAME
    Disable-AddGuests

SYNTAX
    Disable-AddGuests


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

**Explanation:**

I changed `$option` to use `Read-Host` to prompt the executor with a message and then store the typed in response. I scoped `Enable-AddGuests` and `Disable-AddGuests` to the `script` scope. I added the `Default` condition of your `Switch` statement to do something when you do not receive the values you are expecting at the prompt.

Once `Manage-Teams` is executed, you can then gain access to the `Enable-AddGuests` and `Disable-AddGuests` functions in this example because they are scoped to the script scope. By default, those functions would be local to their enclosing scope only, i.e. inside of `Manage-Teams`, and not visible to the outside. You will be able to tab complete them as well. If you want access to those functions without running `Manage-Teams` first, you will need to define and load them outside of `Manage-Teams`.

Comment: @mklement0, This is what I tried to communicate. I added more verbiage. And `function foo { function script:bar { 'ho' }; 'hi'; bar }; foo; bar` should give the desired effect IF we are sticking with nested functions.

Comment: I do feel like explicitly scoping here is possibly just bad design. But I can't see the rest of the script to know why the nesting AND the need to access the functions later is required.

Answer (score 1):

Let me complement [AdminOfThings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57006179/45375) by taking a step back:

**If you want your nested functions to be seen *outside* the function they're defined in, simply define them *directly in that outside scope*.**

By default, like variables, **nested functions are local to the scope they're defined** in and are **also visible in *descendant* scopes**, so that **functions defined as *siblings* in the same scope *can* call each other**.

In defining all your functions in the same scope, you avoid the awkwardness of using `script:` to define functions in a (fixed) *different* scope<sup>[1]</sup>:

- While PowerShell *allows* you to modify other scopes, it's generally a bad idea from the perspective of robustness and maintainability.
- By defining the script-level functions from inside another function, they do not become visible to the script scope *until after the first call* to the defining function.

Therefore, structure your code as follows:

```
# All functions are defined in the same scope, as siblings.

Function Enable-AddGuests {
  # ...
}

Function Disable-AddGuests {
  # ...
}

Function Manage-Teams {

    $option = Read-Host "Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuests"

    switch ($option) {
      'Enable-AddGuests'  { Enable-AddGuests; break }
      'Disable-AddGuests' { Disable-AddGuests; break }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that for code pasted or "dot-sourced" (from a script, using operator `.`) on the *command line*, the `script:` scope refers to the *global* scope.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having a typo in your code.

You are using `Write-Host` cmdlet instead of `Read-Host` cmdlet.

Change this:

```
$option = Write-Host 'Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuest'
```

To this:

```
$option = Read-Host 'Would you like to allow or disable external access? Enable-AddGuests/Disable-AddGuest'
```

Comment: He wrote "originally I had $option = Read-host -prompt "some text"

Comment: This was tested - However still did not make it possible to autocomplete the functions